# JSON editor for moving & copying whole nodes

Tags: json

I am looking for a JSON editor. I want to be able to take nodes from the tree structure and pull them somewhere else in the tree. I have found https://jsoneditoronline.org/ which allows to drag and drop parts from the tree structure somewhere else in the same tree. But the downside of this is that you can't copy nodes whole nodes to insert them somewhere else later on. So I would be looking for an application or a website which allows copying nodes of the tree on top of dragging them. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

[JSONedit](http://tomeko.net/software/JSONedit/)

- drag-and-drop copies node by default, moves node if Shift is pressed (similar to e.g. Total Commander)
- nodes are copied to/from clipboard as plain text - they can be copied from/to other instances or other applications
- JSON from node can be optionally wrapped with node name if node parent is of object type (by default node is copied without name as regular JSON would not allow this)
- nodes can be saved as snippets
- Win32 but should be working with Wine

Answer (score 0):

**macOS App Option:**

If you're on a macOS system [Power JSON Editor](https://tickplant.com/powerjsoneditor/) is a feature rich standalone JSON editor that has been around for many years, and receives regular updates. It does cost $9.99.

Features include:

- Interactive tree and value editor linked to raw code / text view
- Drag-and-drop move, rearrange, and copy nodes
- Drag and drop JSON data between documents or other editors
- Convert node data type between string, number, boolean and null
- Raw JSON text editor
- JSON node editor
- JSON node tree editor
- Beautifying JSON text
- Plug-in Supports
- Scriptable Plug-in Support

[image: Power JSON Editor Code and Tree View]

**Open Source Web Option:**

A browser based open source / cross platform option to try is [JSON Schema Editor](https://json-schema-editor.tangramjs.com). It's Javascript based, and you can install it on your local system with npm.

Features include:

- Tree View of schema elements
- Text View of schema
- Drag and Drop
- Property Inspector of schema elements
- List item

[image]